# Number format exception in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

Hi i am using the Combo box

```
     <form method="get"  action='create_database_1' >
           <select name="User_type">
           <option value="b">Buyer</option>
           <option value="s">Seller</option>
           </select>
      </form>
```

and i am receiving it in Servlet

```
public class create_database_1 extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    String User_type=request.getParameter("User_type");//Line 39
}
}
```

When i select buyer, i am getting the following exception and similarly for "Seller".

I am getting the following exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [create_database_1] in context with path [/Online_Auction] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at create_database_1.doGet(create_database_1.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code that is causing the error?

Comment: What is line 39 of your `Servlet` doing?

Comment: @brso05 Rest of Code is "i am getting other parameters similarly ,which are working fine " and only this part ,i am getting error

Comment: @brso05 String User_type=request.getParameter("User_type"); is line 39

Comment: Post the full code please.

Comment: @BalusC I think if someone is facing this problem as a beginner, this forum should be used to assist them understand it instead of outright telling that question is useless. Also as a user you have a freedom not to answer/ignore this question instead of putting down someone.  This is genuine problem novice/beginner can have.

Answer (score -1):

Can you pull the `.class` files from the server and try to de-compile it?  Looking at the stack trace it looks like line#37 is calling `Integer.parseInt` method. However looking at the code doesn't look that way.  There may be some mismatch in the code you are looking at and the one actually got deployed.

If you need a decompiler, try googling [Java JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/).. this is one of the good decompiler I used.

If you need help locating `.class` file, let me know the server you are using with its version details.